# Deque (time complexity)

Tags: python, data-structures, deque

What is the time complexity for accessing deque[0], deque[somewhere in the middle], and deque[-1]?

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

> Indexed access is O(1) at both ends but slows to O(n) in the middle. For fast random access, use lists instead.

This suggests that the implementation is a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Yes, in CPython a deque is implemented as doubly-linked list of C vectors, where each vector can hold (up to) 64 (pointers to) Python objects.

Comment: So it's still O(n), but using those vectors reduces the coefficient, since you can do O(1) indexing within the vectors.

Comment: Right! Although that wasn't really the intent - the aim was to reduce the memory overhead from 2 pointers per element to 2 pointers per 64 elements. Raymond (Hettinger - the author) said the only reason he supported indexing at all was to give a convenient way to peek at the elements at each end (`d[0]` and `d[-1]`) in O(1) time.

Comment: deque is coded in C, and is long & involved, starting from the top here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c